# bsh/EvalError while accessing jasper report from dynamic web project

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

I have created a jasper report in jaspersoftstudio5.5.0. and I got the desired output in jasperstudio.Now I want to accecc this generated report from my dynamic web project.
    For that I have used the following jar files :

1. commons-digester-2.1.jar
2. iText-2.1.7.jar
3. jasperreports-5.5.0.jar

And added these jars in *classpath* of web project. My aim is to generate this jasper report as a pdf in a new tab of browser window.Here also I have obtained desired output.Unfortunately today morning onwards it is not working properly and not getting pdf in next tab .I got an exception : 
     javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

**Exception details**

type: Exception report

message description

```
The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/EvalError
net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRBshCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRBshCompiler.java:75)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractCompiler.java:340)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getEvaluator(JasperCompileManager.java:265)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createCalculator(JRFillDataset.java:462)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:382)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:81)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.Simply added the jar file bsh-1.3.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

I solved it differently. I edited the jrxml file in a text editor and removed **language="bsh"** from it.